# How to transfer all the elements of a list into a function which asks for *args?

Tags: python, parameters

I'm invoking a third-party function with the head like `def foo(*args)`, so that ordinarily I can use it in this way `foo(a,b,c)`.

But now I have a list, say `li = [a,b,c]`. I don't know how many elements it has until runtime. How to transfer all the elements of the list into the function `foo` as parameters.

I've tried `foo(li)` and `foo(tuple(li))`, but they don't work. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `*` while calling the function, `*` is used for [unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) a sequence into separate positional arguments during function call:

```
foo(*li)
```

demo:

```
>>> def foo(*args): print (args)
>>> foo(*range(10))
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `li` with an `*` before it as in `foo(*li)`:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
foo(*li)
```

For example:

```
>>> def f(*args):
...     print args
...
>>> li = [1,2,3]
>>> f(*li)
(1, 2, 3)
```